# Problema con la visualización de los archivos de visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio

Hola tengo un problema por accidente un plugin me modifico alguna configuración del visual que me tenia los archivos de tipo **.php** como de tipo *php* pero cuando hizo la modificación de la configuración del visual me los puso como de tipo **.sql** pero sigen siendo de extención **php** y al final me quedo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si miran el icono es de tipo **sql** pero el archivo es de extención **.php** que realmente no me fastidia tanto pero el problema es que tambien me modifico el tema del texto y eso si ya fastidia algo por que uno se acostumbra a verlo de ciertos colores ya probe a desinstalar el visual y aun asi sigue igual y ya no se que pueda hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la barra de abajo, donde dice la linea y columna en que estás, los espacios, y entre otras cosas, el lenguaje con el que se interpreta tu código, puedes darle click al nombre del lenguaje y cambiarlo allí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]